# Subspace span from Reduce Row-Echelon

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a matrix in $\mathbb R ^ {5 \times 7}$ of rank 3, so the spans of the columns and rows of $A$ are $3$-dimensional  subspaces of $\mathbb R^5$ and $\mathbb R^7$, respectively. My problem is:

> Find the orthogonal vectors that map this subspace

I started with finding reduced row-echelon form of $A$ and got this:

$$\mathrm{rref}(A) =\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&-.121&.188&-.226&.255\\ 0&1&0&-7.38&3.27 &-.482&-1.832\\ 0&0&1&-14.180& 5.672&.095&-4.856\\0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0&0 \end{bmatrix}$$

This seems very promising but I'm not quite sure how to find the answer from this. I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: Are you familiar with the [Gram-Schmidt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) process? If so, you can produce a sequence of orthogonal basis vectors for each subspace from any independent basis.